# How do I get the "I am free!" achievements?

Tags: achievements, payday-2

In Payday 2, there are four achievements with no image and no description simply called "I", "am", "free", and "!"

[image: I am free!]

How do I get these?  I tried searching, but couldn't find anything.  For example, they're not listed in [either](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=170096597) of the ["full" achievement guides](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=258289639).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[They were placeholders for achievements for the Hoxton Breakout job](https://steamdb.info/app/218620/history/).

- "I" became "Why Don't We Just Use a Spoon?": Complete the Hoxton Breakout heist on any difficulty.
- "am" became "No Bars Can Hold Me": Complete the Hoxton Breakout heist on the Death Wish difficulty.
- "free" became "Havoc in the Streets": Complete the Hoxton Breakout pro ob heist on Death Wish difficulty
- "!" became "Cavity": Hurt an enemy using the Nova's Shank melee weapon.

There was also an achievement called Squeek (or something similar) among those 4, which was renamed to "State of the Art" soon after the Art Gallery heist was released. I managed to get that one before it was renamed or had a description, about 10 minutes after the heist was released.

Comment: Overkill will do this quite often when adding achievements, as new achievements have to be in Steam's systems before they can be triggered in-game.

Comment: Though they are more commonly added only an hour or two before the patch goes live.