# What are the "Željezo se kuje dok je vruce. Cega nema, ne mose se ni uzeti" in the Payday 2 achievements for?

Tags: achievements, payday-2

These achievements just popped up in Payday 2.  NO clue what language they're in, nor why they don't obviously look English like.
[image]
[image]

What are these achievements for?

Comment: Well that was confusing... Was gunna VTC cos I thought it was in Spanish or something... Awkward haha

Comment: @Ben your edit makes this question entirely unsearchable.  People are going to be looking for those specific words since those are used in the achievement itself.

Comment: Fair point. Didn't really think about that, was just thinking of readability.

Comment: I edited the title for better readability. Should not interfere with searchability. I still think that "What does xxx mean" should be enough since payday2 and achievements is covered by the tags for any kind of google search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These were revealed as the achievements for the new "The Bomb" heist released by Overkill for Payday 2:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

It's [Croatian](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Croatian_proverbs).

"Cega nema, ne mose se ni uzeti" is a Croatian proverb. It means, "Nothing ventured, nothing gained."

"Željezo se kuje dok je vruće" means, "Forge (or Strike) while the iron is hot."

As for the reason behind the achievements, the only ones who know that at the moment are the developers themselves. I've asked them about it, and will update should I get a response.

Comment: Thanks for the translation, but what are the achievements for?

Comment: @meme Probably nothing. It's unlikely intentional, at least nothing intended by the developers.

Comment: @RossRidge Well Overkill did something like this before, where they have teaser achievements for future heists, like the ones in this article: http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Trophies_(Payday_2)

Comment: The current theory is that this is related to the First Heist DLC from the Lion Game Lion studio ("The Bomb", according to the Crimefest rewards page), given the language and timing. The actual achievements (with their requirements) will probably be revealed on the day it's released (which has been SOP for all new content adding achievements)

Answer (score 1):

They've done this [several times before](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/189407/how-do-i-get-the-i-am-free-achievements).  They add new achievements with silly names for testing, then later the achievements are renamed and publically released.

So, the achievements cannot currently be earned, but will likely be obtainable in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

They're all achievements for the next upcoming heist which will either be the new bomb heist from the butcher, or the golden grin casino. The fact that the translation is Croatian and that the achievements translate to "Nothing ventured, nothing gained" probably means we're getting the bomb heist, since Lion Game Lion is new to creating heists and is based in Croatia. We don't know what the achievements will be for exactly just yet, but they will almost certainly correlate to one of the new heist maps.