# The good, the bad and the ugly

Tags: payday-2

What are these achievements on PAYDAY 2? The good requires 10 actions. My first guess was placeholders but it seems like they may relate to a future heist, like Golden Grin?

[image]

Comment: They do this before every DLC/update.  See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/189407 and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/201104

Answer (score 2):

"They are for the Western DLC that is not out yet. You can not get them until the DLC comes out. No one knows what they are until the DLC comes out"